# TextView being cut off in Custom ArrayAdapter inside ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, textview

**SOLVED EDIT:** I have fixed the issue. It does not actually make logical sense, but everything other than the checkbox needed to be 'Match_Parent' for both width and height, not 'Wrap_Content' (as strange as that seems).

I am having issues with my custom ArrayAdapter inside of a ListView cutting off text.

A picture is worth a thousand words, so here's a picture of the issue:

[image]

As you can see, the fourth line down is being cut off, on 'cracks'.

Here's the code for the custom adapter:

```
public class CheckListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private int rowPadding = (int) getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.adapter_mediumRowVPadding);
    private int medText = (int) getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.medium_text);

    private Map<String,Boolean> map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
    private List<String> content;

    // Strings incoming are converted to a LinkedHashSet before being used.
    // This ensures that the adapter content will not accidentally change,
    // and that there is only one copy of a given string per adapter.
    // A LinkedHashSet is a HashSet with a predictable iteration order.
    public CheckListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, new ArrayList<String>(new LinkedHashSet<String>(objects)));
    }
    public CheckListAdapter(Context context, List<String> objects) {
        this(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, objects);
    }
    public CheckListAdapter(Context context, String[] objects) {
        this(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Arrays.asList(objects));
    }

    @Override
    public View  getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this.getContext());
        row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greenclicked_background);
        row.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        final CheckBox check = new CheckBox(getContext());
        check.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.gemsgreen_btn_check_holo_light);

        final TextView text = new TextView(getContext());
        LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.FILL);
        text.setLayoutParams(params);
        text.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT);
        final String item = this.getItem(position);

        if(!this.map.containsKey(item)){
            this.map.put(item, false);
        }
        else{
            boolean checked = map.get(item);
            check.setChecked(checked);
        }

        row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean checked = map.get(item);
                checked = !checked;
                map.put(item, checked); 
                check.setChecked(checked);
            }
        });

        text.setText(item);
        text.setMinLines(1);
        text.setMaxLines(10);
        row.addView(check);
        row.addView(text);
        row.setPadding(0, rowPadding, 0, rowPadding);


        return row;
    }

    public Map<String,Boolean> getResults(){
        return map;
    }

}
```

Here's the code for the custom ListView:

```
public class NonScrollListView extends ListView {

    public NonScrollListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();    
    }
}
```

I have been looking for a solution for this issue for almost an hour now, and I have had absolutely no luck. I have tried numerous different approaches using different gravity and layout param settings, but nothing has made it look any different to the way it looks in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define each row layout by xml.
For example: **row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And in **getView()** method, you implements like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // If holder not exist then locate all view from UI file.
        if (convertView == null) {
            // inflate UI from XML file
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_page_listview_items,
                    parent, false);
            // get all UI view
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            // set tag for holder
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // if holder created, get tag from view
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
  //continue your code here
}
 private static class ViewHolder {

        private Checkbox check;
        private TextView text;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            check = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
            text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
    }
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: This doesn't work at all sorry - exact same result as what I posted in the OP.